# How do I access Web service methods using Perl?

Tags: perl

I wish to execute two Web service methods using Perl. I have the URL of this Web service and it has a `.svc` extension. I also have the method names, what they receive as parameters and what they return. How can I do it? If you can be detailed, it will be good.

I tried:

```
use SOAP::Lite;
use SOAP::TRANSPORT;

$client = SOAP::Lite->new();
$client->SOAP::TRANSPORT::HTTP('http://perl-server/perl.svc');
print $client->method_1("hi");
print $client->result();
```

But it returns always `1` and I need to get the answer "true" as a result from `method_1`. I think it returns `1` not from this method, but due to the connection passed successfully.

Comment: Please provide the .svc file for testing.

Comment: With `SOAP::Lite`, you normally set it on its way by calling `proxy` and `uri`, and then it can do enough to remote the method calls. If you are using your own opaque class, and asking us to know what happens between creating a `SOAP::Lite` object and calling a remote method, when all you have is a reference to proprietary code, we're in Underpants Gnome territory.

Comment: hi daxim, Axeman- Can one of you contact me by mail: perlp.svc@gmail.com? or provide me your mail for contact
Thanks in advance,Perl Pro

Comment: .svc address is the proxy\uri? same about .wsdl is the proxy\uri address?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to get this too:

**WSDL** - web service definition (lang) page where SOAP can read a standard format of all the functions/classes available on the server and how to talk to them. Basically a header file.

**URI**  - a class definition page, so that you can write a SOAP server class and then give it to 100s of people and everyone can point to the same definition file so when you update everyone, SOAP clients don't have to update anything

**PROXY** - the actual implementation of the URI class, usually written in wsdl. This is the page you actually connect and talk to.

This is why you need a Proxy and a URI to connect to a SOAP service - definition, and actual server. as for the perl code,

```
my $cli = SOAP::Lite->proxy('proxyurl')->uri('uriurl');

my $call_return_obj = $cli->somefunc('hello');
if ($call_return_obj->faultstring ne '')
{
   print "somethin bad happened: ".$call_return_obj->faultstring."\n";
}
else
{
   my $resultstruct = $call_return_obj->results;
}
```

Then it gets even more tricky. Nested types are expressed as pointers to arrays / hashes filled with more pointers of other arrays or hashes, only the last level of array/hash can have actual values in it. This is how they are returned from SOAP::Lite too.